# How to pass array from excel VBA to matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, excel, vba

I am trying to pass 4 arrays from vba to matlab functions. but it cause type mismatch error.

```
Dim num() as double, txt() as string, pnum as double, ptxt() as string
Set Matlab = CreateObject("matlab.application")
Matlab.Execute ("cd('" & mFilePath & "')")
Matlab.Execute ("get_data(" & num & "," & txt & "," & pnum & "," & ptxt & ")")
```

`num`,`txt`,`pnum` and `ptxt` are 4 arrays needed by my matlab function.

I did successfully pass doubles into another function so I thought it is same way but it is not. Anyone can help?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us whether the type mismatch error is being thrown in VBA because the string you are trying to create in the second `Execute` call can't in fact be created, or whether MATLAB is throwing the error because it can't figure out what you are asking it to do.

But either way, you've most likely got bigger issues: specifically, you haven't passed your data into MATLAB before trying to call the `get_data` function.

You need to use a combination of [PutFullMatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/putfullmatrix.html), [PutWorkspaceData](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/putworkspacedata.html) and [PutCharArray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/putchararray.html)to pass your VBA variables into the MATLAB Workspace before you use [Execute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/execute.html) to call a MATLAB function that uses the data, and then perhaps [GetFullMatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfullmatrix.html) to retrieve the data.  Each of the above links has usage examples.

Comment: Thank you so much and it is working now. The type mismatch is from excel. But as you said, the bigger issues is the main problem.I used PutWorkspaceData function to pass the array into matlab. And that is what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @EricH, On Stack Overflow, the correct way to recognize an answer is to accept it.